# how to calculate total amount of Jenkin's jobs

Tags: jenkins

in our working Jenkins there are hundreds executing jobs. And I'm interesting does Jenkins store somewhere total number of jobs which are currently executing or I should manually calculate it one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `"$N1 - $T jobs"` to display the total number of jobs with this [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Custom+View+Tabs+Plugin)

You can also use:

- $T - The Total number of jobs
- $S - The number of jobs currently Succeeding
- $F - The number of jobs currently Failing
- $U - The number of jobs currently Unstable
- $D - The number of jobs currently Disabled

Answer (score 0):

i´m triying to use this plugin also.
It´s easy to install and configure. All in Configure System.
For example in my screen/case, put this:

**$N1: $T pipelines, $S Ok, $F Failed, $U Unstable, $D DIsabled**

[image: To make anything similar to this...]

[image: All configurations in "Configure System" in Jenkins]